# How do I install node module @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I have been following instructions from https://github.com/babel/babelify and I ran into an error along the way. I run the following line of code:

```
browserify script.js -o bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [ @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react ] --plugins [ @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties ] ]
```

The terminal produces the following error message:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-transform-class-properties' from '/path/to/file' while parsing file: /path/to/file/circle-graph-2.js
```

My package.json file is

```
{
  "name": "robert",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is the third step of my first attempt to learn canvas. I want to improve a piece a made a few weeks ago about the division of [occupations](http://nbremer.github.io/occupations/). The D3.js version has so many DOM elements due to all the small bar charts that it is very slow. Therefore, I hope that a canvas version might improve things",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react",
      "transform-class-properties"
    ]
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babelify": "^10.0.0"
  }
}
```

When I try the following line in the terminal then it says the package isn't found:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties
```

How do I overcome this error message?

Comment: check the official npm package site: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties. You have it there: npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties

Answer (score 21):

Since you are on Babel 7 (based on your `"@babel/core": "^7.1.6"` entry), I think you are looking for [`npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) which is the new version of the plugin for Babel 7. Notice the name change from "plugin-transform-class-properties" -> "babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties".

This was [intentionally done by Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration#switch-to-proposal-for-tc39-proposals-blog-2017-12-27-nearing-the-70-releasehtml-renames-proposal) to make people more aware of where features are in the TC39 process.

If you are actually still on Babel 6 (hard to tell since you have a Babel 7 and Babel 6 entry in your `package.json`, the comment by @Morty is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error for my project, but the `npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` install **was not enough for me.**

Searched for `node-sass for babel 7.11.4` Found the [fix here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10749#issuecomment-815885298)

I was basically in the wrong version so I added `"@babel/core": "^7.13.14"` to my `package.json` file and ran `npm install` again.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using that latest version.
Just run `npx babel-upgrade` and it will display changes you need to update in your babel.rc file